# Не могу найти выложенное приложение в Google Play

Tags: google-play

Добрый день, выложил несколько дней назад приложение в Google play, в консоли разработчика оно открывается на странице google play, а в поиске не могу его найти никак.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего оно просто в самом низу. Попробуйте в поиске ввести пакет вашего приложения. По пакету всегда сразу находит. Если найдет, то все нормально

Comment: Да по пакету находит, спасибо, видно да или в самом низу или надо время чтоб поиск подцепил его.

Answer (score 0):

Когда Вы публикуете свою программу, то она сразу попадает в магазин приложений без всякой модерации.Вот только поиск по магазину Вам может не помочь, нужно какое-то время, чтобы данные в магазине обновились и поисковый робот заметил ваше приложение.

Можете в поисковой строке браузера вставить адрес

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cюда&имя&пакета
```

и в качестве id необходимо указать имя пакета